# Python SFTP issues

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

I wrote a program that will look at a text file and export the errors within the file to another txt file. Then the program goes to a linux host via sftp and transfer the file to a specific location.  However, I'm getting an error when running this program:

```
import os
import sys
import csv
import pysftp 

with open('c:/Python27/log_07032014_1512.txt','r') as inf,    
    open('C:/Python27/Errors.txt','w')as outf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    writer = csv.writer(outf)
    for line in inf:
        if 'Error' in line:
            print line

def sftpExample():
    try:
        s = sftp.Connection('***.***.***.***', username = '******', password = '****')
        remotepath ='/home/*****/BOA.txt'
        localpath = 'C:/Python27/Errors.txt'
        s.put(localpath,remotepath)

        s.close()
    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)

sftpExample()
```

I get the following error when it reads and then tries to transfer the files:

global name 'sftp' is not defined.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Other errors: you create `csv.reader()` and `csv.writer()` objects but never use them. You never put any data in the `Errors.txt` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other way, you can change import line like this,

```
import pysftp as sftp
...
```

Comment: This worked great, do you know why its not writing to the file that I'm trying to write too?

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
s = sftp.Connection(...)
```

you reference a symbol called `sftp` which, as the error message says, has not been defined.

Try this instead:

```
s = pysftp.Connection(...)
```

There are some other errors in your program, but this fix should get you past the first one.

Reference:

- The example on this page: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysftp